# React App cannot be called when created via docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker

I have a simple React app and a spring-boot application as backend. My front end should now communicate with the back end via a defined network. If I pack both services in a docker-compose file and deploy the whole thing, the container with both images is running, but when I call the React page I get an: "This page does not work (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)" error. Where do I have a mistake in reasoning?

My Dockerfile for React:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8083

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

And my compose file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
 backend:
   container_name: "spring-boot"
   build: ./Java   
   networks:
    - bens_network

 frontend:
   container_name: "react-app"
   build: C:\einkauf\einkauf
   ports:
    - 8083:8083
   volumes:
    - './:/app'
    - '/app/node_modules'
   stdin_open: true
   tty: true
   networks:
    - bens_network

  
networks:
 bens_network:
```

Und als letztes der Vollständigerhalber, mein Dockefile für mein Backend:

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY ./target/makecalls.jar makecalls.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java","-jar","makecalls.jar"]
```

Comment: How is the React application calling the backend?  Even though it's getting served from a container, the application itself runs in the browser, which is outside of Docker, so it won't be aware of the Docker networking setup at all.

Comment: @David Maze ok , so how can i handle this ?